# How to make security context available on login page?

Tags: php, security, symfony, silex

I'm currently building a web application with *Silex* and just started implementing the `SecurityServiceProvider`.

I added the following snippet to my bootstrapping code:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls'    => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
            'security' => false,
        ),
        'secured' => array(
            'pattern'   => '^.*$',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login/check'),
            'logout' => array('logout_path', '/logout'),
            'users' => $app['custom.user_provider'],
            'switch_user' => array('parameter' => '_switch_user', 'role' => 'ROLE_IMPERSONATE'),
        ),
    ),
    'security.encoder.digest' => $app->share(function ($app) {
        return new MySQLPasswordEncoder(false);
    }),
));
$app['security.role_hierarchy'] = array(
    'ROLE_ADMIN'    => array('ROLE_STAFF', 'ROLE_BAN_MGR', 'ROLE_IMPERSONATE'),
    'ROLE_STAFF'    => array('ROLE_USER'),
);
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/admin/bans/.*$', 'ROLE_BAN_MGR'),
    array('^/admin/.*$',      'ROLE_STAFF'),
    array('^/account/.*$',    'ROLE_USER'),
    array('^.*$',         ''),
);
```

I want to be able to use the security context (i.e. `is_granted(...)` in templates) on any page, therefore I use `'pattern' => '^.*$', 'anonymous' => true`.
To match the requirement for `login_path` to be outside the secured area, I added the `login` firewall.

Now, the problem is, that the security context is not available on the `/login` page, hence `is_granted(...)` throws an exception:

> AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

I tried adding `'security' => true, 'anonymous' => true` to the `login` firewall, but this leads to inifinite redirections (because `/login` is inside a secured area).

**Question:** How can I make the security context available on the login page (which, by definition, may not be secured)?

Comment: adding anonymous => true to the login route should be enough to do what you want.

Comment: @gunnx I tried that for both `'security' => false` and `'security' => true`, but it didn't work. _mpm_'s answer does well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the first firewall

```
   'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
            'security' => false,
        ),
```

, it is unecessary

and change the last access rule to this

```
array('^/login','IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
```

more details here , the symfony doc is where you should spend most of your time when you have a question regarding silex :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: Works! Thakns for the link - in the Silex documentation on the `SecurityServiceProvider` it just reads _The login_path path must always be defined outside the secured area (or if it is in the secured area, the anonymous authentication mechanism must be enabled -- see below);_. The explanations in the Symfony Books are much better.

Comment: there are config differences between silex and symfony so beware , but most of the things should work out of the box , have fun ! you can check some of my silex scripts here : https://github.com/Mparaiso